# why is memory size being overwritten when I fclose

Tags: c, file, malloc

Warning, Sorry this is my first post so I don't know how to do this.
Just gonna try my best to detail the issue I found

So recently I was working on a PNG decoder, but I stumbled upon a curious "feature"? of file reading.
I kept getting malloc errors like
"malloc.c:2617: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed."
and
"[IHDR] Data: RGBA
malloc(): invalid next size (unsorted)"

So I decided to check the allocated memory's length on a hunch cause I knew I didn't double free my data and I double checked every pointer call for out of bounds things.
And well, upon calling fclose(), the size of my char* would always decrease by 1.
Does anyone know why this happens?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

void checkFP(FILE* fp) {
        if(!fp) {
                printf("couldn't open file\n");
                switch(errno) {
                        case 2:
                                printf("File not found\n");
                                break;
                        case 13:
                                printf("No perms to open file\n");
                                break;
                }
                exit(1);
        }
}

unsigned getAllocLen(char * p) {
        return *(unsigned*)(p-8);
}

int main() {
        unsigned len = 0,
                 orig = 0,
                 l = 0;
        char *buffer,
             *head;

        FILE *fp = fopen("test_1.c", "r");
        checkFP(fp);    

        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        len = ftell(fp);
        l = len;
        buffer = malloc(len);
        head = buffer;
        orig = getAllocLen(buffer);
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        
        while(l) {
                size_t read_bytes = fread(head, 1, l, fp);
                head += read_bytes;
                l -= read_bytes;
        }
        if( fclose(fp) ) {
                printf("Error when closing File\n");
                exit(2);
        }
        if(orig != getAllocLen(buffer)) {
                printf("Uh Ohh Memory corrupted(%p, original len = %u,current len = %u)\n",buffer, orig, getAllocLen(buffer));
                free(buffer);
                exit(3);        
        }

        printf("%s\n",buffer);
        free(buffer);
        return 0;
}
```

Here is the smallest portion of my code I could get showing the error

I noticed that it only happens if I use fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET) or rewind(fp) to reset fp
So when I tried to do close the file first before allocating the memory and then opening it again to read, it didn't corrupt the size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

void checkFP(FILE* fp) {
        if(!fp) {
                printf("couldn't open file\n");
                switch(errno) {
                        case 2:
                                printf("File not found\n");
                                break;
                        case 13:
                                printf("No perms to open file\n");
                                break;
                }
                exit(1);
        }
}

unsigned getAllocLen(char * p) {
        return *(unsigned*)(p-8);
}

int main() {
        unsigned len = 0,
                 orig = 0,
                 l = 0;
        char *buffer,
             *head;
        FILE *fp = fopen("test_1.c", "r");
        checkFP(fp);    

        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        len = ftell(fp), l = len;
        if( fclose(fp) ) {
                printf("Error when closing file\n");
                exit(2);
        }

        buffer = malloc(len);
        head = buffer;
        orig = getAllocLen(buffer);
        
        fp = fopen("test_1.c", "r");
        checkFP(fp);
        while(l) {
                size_t read_bytes = fread(head, 1, l, fp);
                head += read_bytes;
                l -= read_bytes;
        }
        if( fclose(fp) ) {
                printf("Error when closing File\n");
                exit(2);
        }
        if(orig != getAllocLen(buffer)) {
                printf("Uh Ohh Memory corrupted(%p, original len = %u,current len = %u)\n",buffer, orig, getAllocLen(buffer));
                free(buffer);
                exit(3);        
        }

        printf("%s\n",buffer);
        free(buffer);
        return 0;
}
```

I just wanna know why this happens if anyone knows, I will probably just use this code here from now on since it works.

I also noticed something interesting, when the size changed and I tried to free the data, it didn't throw an error, why is that?

Comment: Both snippets are missing a `}` in `main`. It's not obvious from your indentation where you would like to put it though.

Comment: Oh yeah I copied it part by part so I missed it out

Comment: What is `getAllocLen` supposed to be used for?

Comment: And please don't use the comma expression to sequence expressions that should really be separate statements, that makes the code harder to read, follow, maintain and debug.

Comment: Its used to check the space allocated by malloc, calloc or realloc

Comment: So you're trying to bypass or use (abuse?) some implementation details that might be wrong? Who told you about this? Why do you think you need it? Going out of bounds of allocated memory leads to *undefined behavior*. Just don't do it!

Comment: Ok I'll try to make it more readable

Comment: Do you mean to reduce the variable `l` in the `while()` loop?

Comment: Oh and the loop `while(l)` will never end. You never modify the variable `l` inside the loop.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but my knowledge of how dynamic memory allocation works in c is that the size of the memory block is stored in front of the pointer malloc returns, So I used that info to find that there are 8 bytes used to store the size which I get through getAllocLen

Comment: Its a while(L) not 1, the l being a temporary copy of len

Comment: Cause I keep getting malloc errors at fclose, and bro I just started coding, I know I suck and Im bad at it that's why im learning

Comment: Whatever is going on at `p - 8`, you have no business peeking around there. Doing that has undefined behavior. Sidenote: The proper implementation (if it would be ok to peek there) would be something like `size_t getAllocLen(char *p) { return *(size_t *)(p - sizeof(size_t)); }`

Comment: Have you considered checking the return value from `malloc()`? ie. Don't simply presume that system calls _work_...

Comment: If you are opening a PNG file you should open it in binary mode. But the example opens a text file in text mode. The size of the file is not necessarily the number of bytes that will be read.

Comment: And why not read the file in a single read? Your buffer is big enough. Why the loop? And what happens if `read_bytes` is not a multiple of `len`? I'll tell you: `l` goes negative, and your loop never terminates. It should be `while (l > 0)`.

Comment: I see, but then even before I started peeking arnd p - 8, I still got malloc errors, any ideas why?

Comment: I have tried checking, my malloc returns, I just removed it to simplify the example shown

Comment: @WeatherVane, I see, I didn't know that it should be read in binary mode, but wdym by the size of the file not necessarily being the no. of Bytes that will be read?

Comment: As pointed out by @WeatherVane, the data (if loaded) will be "binary"... You won't get anything intelligible with `printf("%s\n",buffer);`

Comment: @user207421 ohh good point, I forgot I was using unsigned ints to keep track of the lengths, I never thought abt it thanks :)

Comment: @Fe2O3, mm yeah I know abt that part, I decode the data in my original PNG reader code knowing the data I am dealing with and checking that it is indeed a PNG file using the magic number

Comment: @KamilCuk, I am not reading a PNG file in this case, this one just reads in a random c file and prints out the code

Comment: A binary file should be opened in binary mode - the name is a good clue. It is because some systems alter the line endings of text files, so you don't always get the actual data that was in the file. And the number of bytes might change, which is not revealed by `ftell()` because it does not parse the whole file to see what will happen to it.

Comment: In any case this is all moot. You should not read entire files into memory in the first place. You can check the magic number with a short read, then you can rewind the file and have your decoder read it chunk by chunk. Allocating buffers the size of a file is doomed to fail sooner or later.

Comment: @WeatherVane You might do the same yourself, mate, and I'm not deleting this one. Just remember that there is no such thing as 'now' or a'within a few seconds' in distributed computing.

Comment: @user207421 I see , I never considered it that much since I was usually just reading smaller files but yeah thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Oh yeah but usually the size of the decoded PNG is larger than the file itself, so is there anything I need to take note of when allocating space for it?

Comment: The message starting “malloc.c” is a common consequence of corrupting memory. Quite likely, something in your original program overruns a buffer or otherwise misuses addresses, regardless of your attempts to check. The sample code you present in this post is different from that code and does not display the original error. Also, you do not show us observed output for the sample code from the question, so we do not know what it is showing you. In particular, we do not see the output of the original or current results from `getAllocLen`.

Comment: Nor have you given sufficient data to reproduce the problem with the sample code, since you did not provide the contents of “test_1.c” or state which compiler (including specific version), C library, and operating system you used.

Comment: There is a bug in your original code. Stop tinkering with the sample code posted in this question, go back to the original code, and find the bug there.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the original getAllocLen returns 1057 while the current one returns 1056, while in the latter code, both are 1057

Comment: gcc -v contain too many letters so I will split it into multiple parts
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object

Comment: --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)

Comment: @EricPostpischil pardon me but I'm not too sure how to tell which version of the C Library I'm using. but test_1.c is the file which contains the code above

Comment: The difference between 1067 and 1066 could be a bit that the memory management software uses to indicate something for itself, such as “end of chain of pointers.” The notion that the bytes before a returned allocation address contain a size is a simplistic assumption used in teaching introductory classes. It is not required by the C standard. It may be used in some C library implementations, but it may be used with modifications (or not used at all). Without internal documentation for the library, you cannot rely on it or interpret 1067 ➝ 1066 as a meaningful change.